# Pokemon Go vibrating too often since last update (0.49.1)

Tags: pokemon-go, android

Since the last update of Pokemon Go (6 December, Android 0.49.1) my game vibrates too often. It is exactly like the 'new-Pokemon-on-the-map', but there are actually no new Pokemon. Is this intended with the new update

It is not because I got another notification, because they all get sent to my wristband, my phone only vibrates on in-game vibrations.

Comment: I noticed this happening on the newest iOS version as well; but, can't figure out the reason behind it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This bug has been fixed as of the latest update, [0.51.0 Android/1.21.0 iOS](http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/ver-update-121916/)

> The bug that caused incorrect vibration notifications has been fixed.

---

According to [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5h7632/false_vibrations/) it is most likely a bug that causes vibrating whenever Nearby (not Sightings) list updates.

Update: Niantic [confirmed](https://twitter.com/PokemonGoApp/status/807469359534895104) that it is a bug.